# How to ensure changes in props do not bubble up?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pointers, vuejs3, components

I realized that my props passed to a component, and changed in the component, may bubble up. This is [mentioned in the documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props).

> When objects and arrays are passed as props, while the child component cannot mutate the prop binding, it **will** be able to mutate the object or array's nested properties.

I recreated a case like that at the [Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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). As you can see, pushing `'hello'` in the `Comp.vue` component changes the value of the prop in the parent `App.vue`.

What the documentation does not suggest is a way to break this binding. I thought that creating unitary refs in the component (from the props object) would break that link but as the code shows this is not the case.

What is the correct way to really seal a component?

Note: I need the variables in the component to be reactive in order to use them in the component template (and have them modified on the fly) This is mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321023/vue-3-why-is-the-parent-updated-when-child-data-changes) and its answers but there is no solution for objects with nested Arrays like in my case.

Comment: This is not specific to Vue but is a general JS knowledge. If you have object reference and need to not modify the original object, you need to clone it. You probably don't need to modify it in a child at all, this is the Vue part, you could establish two-way binding and modify it in a parent

Comment: @EstusFlask I need to modify it in the child, and then `emit` the changed object back to the parent

Comment: In this case it makes more sense to make a copy at the time when a value is emitted, this way the prop stays reactive all the time, `emit('update:modelValue', [...props.data.Books, newBook])`. In this case you can make use of v-model. There may be cases when a child needs fully detached state, e.g. it's a form that can be reset, but this case doesn't look like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to break the reactivity link by spreading the props into the component's reactive variable. For the code mentioned in the Vue Playground, this means having

```
const books = ref([...props.data.Books])
// was: const books = ref(props.data.Books)
```

From there on, `books` is reactive within the component and inherits of the props values, but its changes are not propagated back to the parent.

Comment: This is shallow copy, If you mutate books elements, the changes will be propagated to the parent any way

Comment: @EstusFlask: are you sure of that? I just replaced `const books = ref([...props.data.Books])` in the Vue Playground code and the array is not updated in the parent (https://shorturl.at/mpxC6)

Comment: In this case element is a string, so this will work. In case it's an object, it won't

Comment: @EstusFlask: ah ok, because it is a shallow copy I would get an Array of strings which will not be affected, but if this was an Array of Objects, then I would actually get an Array or pointers/references, which would be mutable. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

At first, I'm not very clear what you want to ask, Your code in playground has show me that you may want to use the [writable-computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed),

The `const name = ref(props.data.Name)` will only create a new ref with `props.data.Name` as default value, so it will not change when props update.

Then about your question

> What is the correct way to really seal a component?

I think that change the prop's property is not a good way however vue allow you do this. The good way to do is update the value with event. And the `v-model` is also a prop and a event `v-model:visible="xxx"` => `:visible="xxx"` `@update:visible="xxx"`

You may can create a ref in your component and watch your props, when the ref change, make a event to ask parent component and when the prop change update your ref. Also it have alreay been implemented in [useVModel in @vue/use](https://vueuse.org/core/useVModel/), I suggest that you can try to use it and read their codes.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I was not asking how to propagate the change back, but rather how to **not** propagate it back due to JS' pass-by-reference. Please see my answer for a possible solution.